# Change background color of event on click in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I want to change the background color of an event on click. The below code is doing that, but I could not figure out how to get back to the default background color of the event when I click on another event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#adsm_calendar").fullCalendar({
        height: 575,
        events :"/get_calander_events",

        eventClick:function(cal_event){

          cal_event.backgroundColor = 'blue';

          $('#adsm_calendar').fullCalendar( 'rerenderEvents' );
          $.ajax("<%= the_path %>", {
              type: "POST",
              data: { id: cal_event.id }
          });
        },

        header:{
            left: "prev,next today",
            center: "title",
            right: "month,agendaWeek,agendaDay"
        }
    });
  });
```

I tried different ways, but nothing fixed it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could save your temporary coloured event in an variable, and then returning it to your previous color:

```
var prevClickedEvent;
var myDefaultBackgroundColor = 'white';
eventClick:function(cal_event){
      //Previous clicked to default color
      if(prevClickedEvent){
           prevClickedEvent.backgroundColor = myDefaultBackGroundColor;
      }   

      cal_event.backgroundColor = 'blue';
      prevClickedEvent = cal_event;


      $('#adsm_calendar').fullCalendar( 'rerenderEvents' );
      $.ajax("<%= the_path %>", {
          type: "POST",

          data: { id: cal_event.id }
      });
    },
```

Anyway, I would use `className` property to add/remove a class of the event, so managing it by css you don't need to rerender the object.

I've created [a plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/EWzNQ3) where you can reproduce it.

Comment: Hi mario thanks for your help,but am getting an error as below,couldnt fix

SyntaxError: missing : after property id
var prevClickedEvent;

Comment: Hi, @nagen. I've just created a plnkr and updated my answer with a link. Take a look at it and keep special care where you locate the variables definitions.

Comment: yes @mario ,the problem was with location of variables,its working now,thank you very much

Comment: Welcome, @nagen. Then maybe you consider accepting this answer.