# How to Change all FullCalendar 's events color onClick?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I want to change the color of the selected event onClick , in addition when i select another event in my calendar  i want the previous event to get it's initial color.

this is what i tried :

```
eventClick:function(info){

       
    if($(this).css('background-color')=='rgb(58, 135, 173)'){
            $(this).css('background-color','red');
       }
                                                 
   else{
     $(this).css('background-color','rgb(58, 135, 173)');
       }
  }
```

i tried to add this line before the if block , but nothing has changed :

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar(" eventColor", "#378006");
```

so any idea ?

## Update

i find in [docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dynamic-options) that i can set dynamically the options of the calendar ,i did that:

```
$('#calendar').setOption('eventColor','blue')
```

but i get an error telling that *setOption isn't a function* ?

Comment: "previous"...you mean the event which was the last one to be selected before this one, or the one which is just before it by time? It's not clear.

Comment: `$('#calendar')` is not how you refer to a fullCalendar in version 4...it's [not a jQuery plugin anymore](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v3). Just `calendar.setOption(...` should be correct, assuming `calendar` is the name you gave to your calendar variable when you initialised it, and assuming it's in scope (neither of which I can be certain of from your 1-line code snippets).

Comment: Also, if you run "setOption" to set `eventColor`, this will set the colour for _all_ events, not just one. If you want it to set the colour for a specific event, you need to get that event object and change it.

Comment: I'm also trying to use `setOption`, but am getting `setOption isn't a function`. 
```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar($('#calendar'))
calendar.render()

calendar.setOption('slotMinTime', '05:00:00');
calendar.setOption('slotMaxTime', '21:00:00');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35797928/change-background-color-of-event-on-click-in-fullcalendar/35798754#35798754) , just add a variable to store the previous event and change its background on next Click :

```
        var previousClickedEvent;
       $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                       header: {
                       left: 'prev,next today',
                       center: 'title',
                       right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                        },
                         locale:'fr',
                         defaultDate: '2016-10-01',
                         navLinks: true,
                         eventLimit: true,
                         events:events,

                         eventClick:function(info){                                                               
                             if(previousClickedEvent){

                                    previousClickedEvent.css('background-color','rgb(58, 135, 173)');
                                }

                                  /*some code*/


                              if($(this).css('background-color')=='rgb(58, 135, 173)'){

                                   $(this).css('background-color','red');
                               }
                              else{

                                  $(this).css('background-color','rgb(58, 135, 173)');
                               }                                   
                          previousClickedEvent=$(this);}})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
eventClick: function(event) {
    event.backgroundColor = 'red';
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
},
```

Comment: no man , i saw that ,  that works on the selected event ,what i want is to reinisialize the color of a previous event when i click on a new event